# ARView Session Variable Not Allowed?

Tags: swift, realitykit

I am feeling a bit silly asking this question. But I really could not figure it out. I must miss an import Swift convention.

In the [ARView document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview), it mentioned that ARView conforms to ARSessionProviding protocol and have "session" variable. However, when I am using XCode, it kept shows me an error :

> Value of type 'ARView' has no member 'session'

The xcode project (xcode-beta) is set to  "iOS 13" and the simulator is set to "iPhone SE(13.5)" .

The [source code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) was from Apple (and it seems seriously out of date). The error is from "arView.session"

```
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
.....
arView.session.run(configuration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have `import RealityKit`. Also, ensure that you are targeting an actual device instead of an iOS simulator

Comment: What do you mean by "not targeting an iOS simulator"? I probably missed this point. I am building to run on a simulator. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can't build that on simulator. Select an actual device and try it again

Comment: Do you mind to explain a bit more? Is it about APIs on Intel/AMD vs ARM? I guess more generally, how could I tell which API is on which platform? Thank you.

Comment: I believe the idea is the same even though I am using ARKit. ARKit does not support iOS simulator because it needs the access of the TrueDepth camera for creating the AR scene view. Based on the apple doc for reality kit: "Use the RealityKit framework to implement high-performance 3D simulation and rendering. RealityKit leverages information provided by the ARKit framework to seamlessly integrate virtual objects into the real world." I believe in this case the reason is the same according to the doc

Comment: Yeah! You are right! Thank you so much! Without a device, one could not even write a piece of code .... sigh ..